# PHP Generate number based on chance

Tags: php, math

What I want to do is generate a float between 1.00 to 200.00, let's call this number `X`. The X determines how much a user "wins", think of it like a multiplier on a casino. The user bets 10$, `X` is 23.21, the user wins `10*23.21`.

If the house and the user should have the same odds (+/- 0) in the long run, the chance of `X` being, for example, 200.00 should be `1/199 - 1/200`. This means `Y=1/(X-1) - 1/X` where Y = percentage of the chance of `X`.

The percentage `Y` should be randomized and I was thinking to do a `frand(0, 100, 15)`. Where:

```
function frand($min, $max, $decimals = 0) 
{
  $scale = pow(10, $decimals);
  return mt_rand($min * $scale, $max * $scale) / $scale;
}
```

This means we will know Y, and therefor the next step should be using `Y=1/(X-1) - 1/X` to determine `X`. However, I do not know how I can achieve this in PHP. Other ways for the same function:

```
Y = 1/(X - 1) - 1/X
X^2 - X = 1/Y
X(X - 1) = 1/
```

So, my question is; how do I solve the `X` OR is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: Let me get this clear. A float between 1.00 and 200.00, so for instance 123.45 would be one of the 19901 possible values?

Comment: Since you rand a multiplier `>=1`, the user will never loose since he will at least get back his bet (1x is the worse case). So what you mean by *house and the user should have the same odds*?  Odds for what?

Comment: Yes, KIKO Software, that is correct.

Comment: Then the change of x = 200.00 is 1/19901 and not 1/199 - 1/200.

Comment: That is true, dragoste. It should actually go from 0-200 then? But then the chance for 1 would be, 1/0 - 1/1. Which is <0

Comment: KIKO, shouldn't it be 1/(X*10 - 1) - 1/(X*10) since I include 2 decimals?

Comment: No. The change of each number is simply one devided by the amount of possible numbers: 1/(20000-100+1). The change doesn't depend on the number at all. This is the basis of a flat random distribution: https://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/williams/science.plt/4/6/planet-docs/science/random-distributions.html#(part._.The_.Flat__.Uniform__.Distribution)

Comment: Oh then I must've misunderstood you earlier. Since the chance of the `X` being 200 is much lower than 1.